# How do you connect use pyodbc to connect to MS SQL server when password has escape characters

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm writing a connection string in Python that connects to a MS SQL Server database.  I am using pyodbc.  Previously, I had used SqlAlchemy and that worked fine.  However, I'd like to NOT use SQLAlchemy because I'd like to keep things simple.

The problem is, when I try to create a connect string and the password has "\" (escape character) in it (mine has two), something happens when the password string is passed from pyodbc to the underlying SQL Server ODBC driver and my login fails.

I've tried all sorts of url encoding and I still can't get it to work.

I'm sure this problem has been solved before, but I can't seem to find any solution that's pertinent to my use-case.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried replacing the backslash with 2 backslash characters?

Comment: Perhaps specify the connection string for pyodbc as a raw string. Something like `pypyodbc.connect(r'Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};Server=yourserver;UID="UserName";PWD="pass\word";')` so python doesn't get its grubby mitts on it and try to escape.

Comment: Yep, I tried that, to no avail.  I didn't have to do anything to it using SQLAlchemy.  I stepped through the SQLAlchemy code and it doesn't look like it's doing anything special with the password either.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Also, FWIW, ODBC does not have any problem dealing with passwords that contain backslashes. [This code](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/77a2de327571f51b6244a552332209e4) works fine.